# Обработка кнопки Ок на виртуальной клавиатуре

Tags: java, android, события, клавиатура, android-edittext

Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки Ок на виртуальной клавиатуре вызывалось событие check(View v) и при этом клавиатура НЕ закрывалась. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это EditText вы можете воспользоваться подобным методом:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: А где тут вызов процедуры check(View v)?

Comment: Я вам вроде как описал как отследить клик на кнопку клавиатуры, а потом проверяйте все что вам нужно. Единственное я не понимаю откуда эта кнопка должна нажиматься, потому и приложил EditText

Comment: Кнопка нажимается из EditText, вы все правильно поняли. Ваш код отлично работает, спасибо))) И еще, вместо `if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            return true;
        }` можно просто в конце написать не return false, а return true. Вобщем я там предложил правку, проверьте.

Comment: да но если сделать так как вы предлагаете в правке то не будет проверки на какую именно вы кнопку нажали, в текущем варианте все правильно сделано и ничего меня не нужно :)

Comment: @Andrew А как вы увидели мою правку, ее вроди бы еще не проверили? На счет правки - у меня работает. Кстати вы не знаете как сделать чтобы вместо текста "ок" там было что-то другое?

Comment: ваша правка видна при достижении определенного уровня репутации, по поводу кнопки `ок` - это очень маловероятно, потому что клавиатура не ваша, а системная и такое будет сложно сделать да и не факт что получится

Comment: @Andrew Но в браузере хром как-то сделали чтобы там была кнопка перейти, значит это возможно. Вы не знаете как?

Comment: в xml можно установить несколько вариантов:
`1.android:imeOptions="actionGo"
2. android:imeOptions="actionDone"
3. android:imeOptions="actionNext"
4. android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
5. android:imeOptions="actionSend"`

Comment: @Andrew У меня 2 вопроса. xml код писать к edittext? Можно ли туда загнать свой текст(любой текст)?

Comment: 1. да в xml в поле для ввода, 2. за свой текст я вам уже сказал - без бубна никак, либо используйте строки выше, либо создавайте свою клавиатуру для проекта - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android )

Comment: @Andrew за информацию про xml спасибо, но вот хоть какую я туда imeotions не вставлял моя правка работает)

Comment: вам нужно сделать условие при котором только при нажатии на кнопку выполняется действие, без условия по логике вы можете нажать на любую кнопку и будет выполняться функция,и я бы хотел еще раз уточнить что @SergeiBuvaka дал правильный ответ который следует использовать :)

Comment: @Andrew Вы имеете в виду обычные кнопки клавиатуры(абв)? Если да, то при нажатии на них слушатель не срабатывает.

Comment: @Andrew А вы не знаете как нажать на кнопку Shift на клавиатуре?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961813/in-android-edittext-how-to-force-writing-uppercase

Comment: при появлении новых вопросов, лучше опубликовать их как вопрос, а не создавать развернутое обсуждение)

Comment: @Andrew Просто про Shift это мелкий вопрос поэтому я думаю его не стоит задавать как отдельный вопрос чтобы не засорять сообщество)